# Como retornar somente os dados ref. ao usuário logado

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Tenho uma tabela que retorna os seguintes dados de um banco SQL Server:

- KM inicial;
- KM Final;
- Litros;
- Valor R$.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria que so retorna-se os valores ref. ao usuario logado.

Na tabela no BD, tenho uma coluna que salva o nome do usuario (Obs: sei que o nome nao é o melhor jeito, e sim a ID do usuario, mas no momento vamos trabalhar com nomes).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`Controller`:

```
public class CombustivelController : Controller
{
    private CombustiveisContext db = new CombustiveisContext();

    // GET: Combustivel
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await db.CombustivelModels.ToListAsync());
    }

    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Como poderia fazer essa consulta?

Comment: o que é "usuário logado"? É o usuário do SQL Server ou o aplicativo possui uma tabela interna de usuários?

Comment: @JoséDiz usuário logado via `Identity`, usuário logado na pagina.

Comment: Agora o contexto ficou claro ("usuário logado na página"). É que na descrição consta somente "usuário logado" e o tópico tem a tag sql-server, o que me induziu a sugerir as funções internas do SQL Server que fornecem informações sobre usuário/logon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se deseja obter o nome usuário logado, basta utilizar o seguinte código:

```
public class CombustivelController : Controller
{
    private CombustiveisContext db = new CombustiveisContext();

    // GET: Combustivel
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var name = User.Identity.Name;
        return View(await db.CombustivelModels.Where(c => c.UserId == name).ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Porém, essa não é uma abordagem muito indicada. Aconselho a salvar o **ID** do usuário corretamente.

Para obter o **ID** do usuário logado, basta utilizar este código:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
 ...
 public class CombustivelController : Controller
    {
        private CombustiveisContext db = new CombustiveisContext();

        // GET: Combustivel
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var userId= User.Identity.GetUserId();
            return View(await db.CombustivelModels.Where(c => c.UserId == userId).ToListAsync());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação de como obter o Id do usuário, mas minha duvida é como carregar a lista, trazendo somente os dados do usuário logado.

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel Observe que adicionei um `Where()` em sua consulta. Nesse `Where()` eu retorno os dados somente do usuário logado: `db.CombustivelModels.Where(c => c.UserId == userId)`

Comment: Perfeito Obrigado